# Testing calendar dates in database

Tags: manual-testing

I'm testing a registration system which involves a sender sending a daily update file to be processed to update the database systems. In this file there is a date field, and if populated, the date field for a particular record will change and the system will change the previous record's date to be the updated date - 1 calendar day. So if the updated file has a date of 31/3/14, the previous record will have a date of 30/3/14.

So how would I be able to test this properly apart from the obvious? The only one I can think of is around the beginning/end of year, so for eg, if the update file contained a date of 1/1/14, then the system should update the date of the previous record to 31/12/13.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

- Leap Year (March 1st) - Roll back to Feb 29th
- Non Leap Year (March 1st) - Roll back to Feb 28th
- Test for month with 30/31 days
- Check for Year End, New Year (Correct month and year applied)
- Invalid Date Format Validations. Invalid patterns removed  (MM/DD/YYYY, DD/MM/YY, DD/MM/YY HH:MM:SS)
- Records with and Without zero are handled properly, 01/01/2014 is handled same as 1/1/2014

Comment: Good answer. A few of these might help, too: http://www.allthingsquality.com/2010/04/general-input-tests-for-date-fields.html

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Siva's answer, I would add that there are many valid date/time formats that are different from each other. What all date formats are allowed?

This can also be applied to the time format if you have timestamps. Is 24 hour time supported, etc.?

What about timezones? If an update is pushed from a server in India and processed on a server in the US, does anything special happen (shift time to US time and then -1 day). Maybe this doesn't apply to your system.